# Memory leak NMAP on Ubuntu 16 LTS

Tags: ram, nmap, memory-leak, openvas

Using OpenVas for security scans
NMAP (`7.01-2ubuntu2`) for Ubuntu 16 LTS has a huge memory leak.

I have 64GB RAM on server and takes a few hours to build up and then server stop responding.

```
 12974 root   21   1  189380  23240   2196 R 100.0  0.0   0:16.52 openvassd                                                             
 10670 root   20   0 96.592g 0.060t   1956 D  35.5 97.6   1:28.53 nmap
```

Any workaround?

Comment: Which command did you start nmap with?

Comment: 7.01 is a very old release (2 years old, 11 releases since). Nmap 7.25BETA2 had a fix for a memory leak in NSE. And as @vidarlo said, we can't really know what's going on unless we know what options you gave to Nmap.

Comment: Nmap is open by openVAS. (Sorry I don't know what the syntax is)

The version of NMAP is what I get from Ubuntu update.